# How can I switch the direction of a Curve on Blender 2.8?

Tags: bezier-curves, shortcut, path

How can i switch (invert) the direction of a curve to the opposite direction, in Blender 2.8?

It seems that the shorcut for this option has changed.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In edit mode:

- select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
- *right click* > *Switch Direction*

  (or *right click* > <kbd>D</kbd>)

There isn't a more direct shortcut, but these are pretty quick! However, if you need to use this option so often that you'd like to only use the keyboard, you can *Right click* on the "*Switch Direction*" menu option and do "*Add shortcut*".

By design, since Blender 2.80, the F5 to F8 keys are not assigned to any default shortcut, so that add-ons and users can define their favorite ones.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 11):

It's in *Segments > Switch Direction*

[image]