# Curves not showing direction in edit/object mode

Tags: blender-osm

I'm importing roads from OpenStreet Map. They are imported as curves. However, these curves seemingly do not have direction. I have tried to change them to Bezier curves and "switch direction", but these do not work.
What can I do to display/set the directions of my curves?
[image]

Comment: Hello :). It should work like this: [How can I switch the direction of a Curve on Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/163052/78972). What exactly isn't working for you?

Answer (score 10):

2D curves have no normals.

For 3D curves enable show normals in the overlays section.

[image]

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work. Also, if it helps, my curve is displayed in blocks of 3 vertices. So it's three vertices connected by edges, then an empty space to the next block of 3 vertices. Thanks by the way!

Comment: it is hard to guess. plesase edit your question and show an image that shows what you get

Comment: Are the curves 2D or 3D?

Comment: It's 2D. Uploaded the photo.

Comment: 2d curves have no normals.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are some controls for curves under Viewport Overlays, here:

[image]

[image]

Click here and choose All, or try increasing the Normals slider.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an add up of susu's answer with enabling the normals.
Just next to the checkbox there is a slider to control the size of them. If after checking the normals box you still can't see anything, try making the normals size bigger. Depending on the scale or distance it can happen you won't see them because they are too small.

This might sound obvious and stupid, but I think is something anyone could easily miss, specially new people.

I hope it can help ;)

Comment: Yes, and since the slider only goes up to 2, you may have to manually overdrive the value by typing in a value larger than 2. (In my case, that was 50, since the scene scale size had been set to 0.01 for Unreal Engine export).